# bash stdout and ampersands

Tags: bash, csv, text, echo

I have a large csv (foobar.csv, delimiter = tab) that has content like this

```
foo /Category1 & Category2
bar /Category3 & Category4
...
```

This command

```
cut foobar.csv -f2 | uniq
```

will print

```
/Category1 & Category2 
/Category3 & Category4
```

and so on...

I would like to have it on one line so I tried

```
echo -n "$(cut foobar.csv -f2 | uniq)"
```

but this will print something cryptic such as

/Cat4ory

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening or how I can bring the Categories on line?

Ideally I would like to transform the output to an array that I can use in a for loop.

Comment: That echo command isn't going to remove internal newlines since you quoted the command substitution. Effectively that `echo` is pointless. Make sure your file doesn't have DOS newlines. They confuse output. If you want to read input by line into an array see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a `tr -d '\n'` at your cmd pipe.If there is dos newline, put `tr -d '\r\n'`